# Bash Script, Kill process by pulling from PID file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, glassfish, pid

This is what I have right now in the bash script:

```
ps aux | grep glassfish | grep domain1 | gawk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

The problem with this is that if someone else is logged in and pulling something related to glassfish, it wil pull that PID as well. Thus resulting in killing the wrong PID.

So My question is how do I fix what I have to only pull the correct PID, and how do I rewrite it to pull the PID from the PID file that glassfish generates.

Comment: kill -9 is a bit harsh, are you sure you need this kind of violence? :-)

Answer (score 17):

Edit the script that starts glassfish and place something like `echo $$ > /path/to/PID-file` (this can contain `~` for home directory or some other mechanism like `$USER` to make user specific) on the line immediately following the line starting the process. You can then kill the correct process using `kill $(cat /path/to/PID-file)`.

Comment: By the way the ps a (removing the "only yourself") , is not in the code. I mistakenly pasted this from old code.

Comment: @jordanm Performance impact of using cat here will barely be measurable, let alone noticeable to the user. I'll take better readability *any* day. If it makes you feel better you can replace it with `less` instead, but `$(< file)` will confuse the vast majority of newbies.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux | grep ^$USER | grep glassfish | grep domain1 | gawk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Below i did mistake with `ps` switches, so above grep should be fine.

---

<strike>ah it is not working, `ps` could be use like this `ps -ao pid,tty,comm -u $USER`, this grep above should be fine ...</strike>

> someone else is logged in ...

<strike>If so, add switch -u</strike>

```
ps aux -u $USER | grep glassfish | grep domain1 | gawk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

<strike>$USER is user name that will be selected and listed, by default should be already set in OS environment. Multiple users could be selected by comma `ps aux -u root,$USER`</strike>

<strike>**Take a note:** If there is no specific username in the system, ps will throw *ERROR: User name does not exist.*</strike>

<strike>Read `man ps` for more.</strike>

> **-u userlist**     Select by effective user ID (EUID) or name.
>                   This selects the processes whose effective user name or ID is in userlist. The effective user ID describes the user whose
>   file access permissions are used by the process (see geteuid(2)).
>   Identical
>                   to U and --user.